# identify whether a string is stopword or not in python

Tags: python

I want to identify whether a string is a stopword or not, I write a python cod for this but i did not get the correct result
code is

```
stopwords = [ "a","about","above","after","again","against","all","am","an","and","any","are","aren't","as","at","be","because","been","before","being","below","between","both","but","by","can't","cannot","could","couldn't","did","didn't","do","does","doesn't","doing","don't","down","during","each","few","for","from","further","had","hadn't","has","hasn't","have","haven't","having","he","he'd","he'll","he's","her","here","here's","hers","herself","him","himself","his","how","how's","i","i'd","i'll","i'm","i've","if","in","into","is","isn't","it","it's","its","itself","let's","me","more","most","mustn't","my","myself","no","nor","not","of","off","on","once","only","or","other","ought","our","ours    ourselves","out","over","own","same","shan't","she","she'd","she'll","she's","should","shouldn't","so","some","such","than","that","that's","the","their","theirs","them","themselves","then","there","there's","these","they","they'd","they'll","they're","they've","this","those","through","to","too","under","until","up","very","was","wasn't","we","we'd","we'll","we're","we've","were","weren't","what","what's","when","when's","where","where's","which","while","who","who's","whom","why","why's","with","won't","would","wouldn't","you","you'd","you'll","you're","you've","your","yours","yourself","yourselves"];
file="C:/Python26/test.txt";
f=open("stopwords.txt",'w');
with open(file,'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines();
    for word in lines:
        if word in stopwords:
            f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'1'"\n");            
        else:
            f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'0'"\n");
    f.close();
```

at result i got 0 against every token/string stored in the test.txt file

Comment: You're writing the same string `word.strip("\n")+"\t"'0'"\n"` to `test.txt` regardless of whether it's a stopword or not. Are those two strings supposed to be different?

Comment: now i edited the question

Comment: I have simple english text in test.txt containing stopwords and non stopwords both

Comment: Could you give an example of how test.txt looks like. Is every word in the file on a separate line, because your current code looks like it is comparing each line with the stopwords, and not the individual words in the line. When you write "for word in lines:", word will actually correspond to the whole line, which is unlikely to be just one word.

Comment: My txt file is each token or string per line                                                                                                      likeIL-2
gene
expression
and
NF-kappa
B
activation
through
CD28
requires
reactive
oxygen
production
by
5-lipoxygenase

Answer (score 5):

Basically you are comparing a **line** with a **stop-word** from **stop-words list** because you are iterating on **sentences/lines** returned by `rf.readlines()` not on individual **words**. You need to iterate each **word** in each **line** so an extra for loop is required. Thus add an extra for loop as shown below to iterate over each word in each line:

```
for line in lines:
    for word in line.split():  # split() splits the line on white-spaces
        if word in stopwords:
            f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'1'"\n");            
        else:
            f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'0'"\n");
    f.close();
```

Comment: because i have a single word in a single line

Comment: in that case your test condition should be `if test_word.strip() in stopwords` to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays in how you are splitting the `line`, A nice option is to use list comprehension, [Split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) the string to list and iterate the list.

```
stopwords = ["a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any", "are", "aren't", "as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "before", "being", "below", "between", "both", "but", "by", "can't", "cannot", "could", "couldn't", "did", "didn't", "do", "does", "doesn't", "doing", "don't", "down", "during", "each", "few", "for", "from", "further", "had", "hadn't", "has", "hasn't", "have", "haven't", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "he's", "her", "here", "here's", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "how's", "i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm", "i've", "if", "in", "into", "is", "isn't", "it", "it's", "its", "itself", "let's", "me", "more", "most", "mustn't", "my", "myself", "no", "nor", "not", "of", "off", "on", "once", "only", "or", "other", "ought", "our", "ours    ourselves", "out", "over", "own", "same", "shan't", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "shouldn't", "so", "some", "such", "than", "that", "that's", "the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "there's", "these", "they", "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "this", "those", "through", "to", "too", "under", "until", "up", "very", "was", "wasn't", "we", "we'd", "we'll", "we're", "we've", "were", "weren't", "what", "what's", "when", "when's", "where", "where's", "which", "while", "who", "who's", "whom", "why", "why's", "with", "won't", "would", "wouldn't", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "you're", "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves"]

def stop_word_test(test_word):
    if test_word in stopwords:
        return test_word.strip("\n")+"\t"'1'"\n"
    else:
        return test_word.strip("\n")+"\t"'0'"\n"

with open("c:\\stopwords.txt", 'w') as write_file:
    with open("C:\\test.txt", 'r') as r_file:
        [write_file.write(value) for value in [stop_word_test(word) for line in r_file.readlines() for word in "".join((char if char.isalpha() else " ") for char in line).split()]]
```

At the above example we are splinting the line by any punctuation which is not a letter.

Also there is no need in `;` at python.